# How far behind is the data returned by calls supposed to be?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I understand that the data sourced to the API are cached, but I'm seeing some fairly extreme discrepancies between reputation reported by the API and apparent activity on the site.

**For example:**

Jon Skeet's [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167649/keyvaluepair-is-nothing/3167673#3167673) has five upvotes and was accepted, so the total rep should be 65.  The question was asked three hours ago at the time of this posting, and Jon's answer came immediately after.  Jon's rep reported for that answer at this time, by the API, is still only 15.

How often is the cache used by the API updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a pretty good chance the Jon has hit the cap today.  So he only got rep for the accept.

The data is real time, so it is actually cached less than the website.

Comment: **DUHH...** facepalm/headsmack... I need to find a guinea pig that has non-exponential rep earning potential!  So rep for accepts are not controlled by the cap?

Comment: @Dave Nope, you will always get 15 points from an accept vote.  No matter how much rep you have already gotten that day.

Comment: @dave  facepalm/headsmack == PWOP!

Answer (score 3):

Question and answer data is almost instantaneous.

I regularly see Questions with soapi-notify that are 7 seconds old.

Answers take a few more seconds.

Votes and acceptance sometimes take 30 seconds to a minute to register. Hard to be exact unless I am polling at a rate that may draw unwanted attention.

So yeah, there is *some* latency but nothing more than a minute or two worst case.